# How to fix matplotlib.pyplot problem in installed matplotlib in python

Tags: matplotlib

I am new in python and last month I have installed matplotlib module in my python and using that I have also done some codes successfully. But now suddenly I don't know why my matlpotlib module is not working. When I write **"import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"** it shows the error **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package"** and the codes that was done before are also not working and showing the same error."import matplotlib" statement works properly in command prompt and IDLE. What am I suppose to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a python file called `matplotlib`?

Comment: Ohh....yeahhh....now i get it.....Thank you so much sir.